# Больше случайности в C++

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Допустим, есть цикл, смысл которого в один проход 20 раз вызвать функцию `srand`. Поскольку `srand` для генерации чисел использует текущее время, то выполняя цикл быстрее,чем в одну секунду, я на выходе получаю 20 одинаковых чисел.
Пример кода:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> //srand
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int random_11()
{
     srand(time(NULL)); //Вызываем функцию рандома. Описание функции по ссылке: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/
    int random_num = rand() % 100; // Генерируем число в пределах 100
    return random_num;
}
int main()
{
    int ar[20];
    int n;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        n = random_11(); // Вызываем функцию для генерации случайного числа
        ar[i] = n;
        cout << ar[i] << '\n';
    }

}
```

На выходе, мы получим 20 одинаковых значений, которые были сгенерированны в данную секунду. Если изменить значение 20 на, скажем 200,000, то мы будем иметь несколько разных чисел, которые были сгенерированны в течении нескольких секунд.

Суть вопроса:
Как реализовать генерацию случайных чисел не привязанную ко времени?

Парни, прошу прощения за свой кретинизм и плохое чтение мануала.
По совету совету Владимира Мартьянова, я просто переместил `srand(time(NULL))` в main.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> //srand
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

int random_11()
{
    int random_num = rand() % 100; 
    return random_num;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int ar[20];
    int n;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        n = random_11(); 
        ar[i] = n;
        cout << ar[i] << '\n';
    }

}
```

Прошу понять, простить и ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

srand() нужно использовать один раз, а не в цикле. Для отвязки от времени передайте аргументом этой функции не время.

Comment: Вот так и рождаются нездоровые сенсации... Вы чему молодежь по сути учите - что `srand()` **можно** вызывать часто, что это неплохо... только не время передавайте. Мда...

Comment: А где я написал что нужно использовать часто? "srand() нужно использовать один раз" - прямая цитата.

Comment: на самом деле "передать не время" - значит передать, что то константное (скорее всего). А это "ухудшит случайность"

Comment: @KoVadim на самом деле передать не время - младший DWORD счетчика тактов, координаты мыши во время вызова, еще куча вариантов. И они - не константы.

Comment: "младший DWORD" это формально тоже время. А мышки может и не быть

Comment: @KoVadim Только в случае, если он увеличивается на одинаковое число за одинаковое время. Учитывая многоядерные машины, управление частотой и т.п. я в этом не уверен.

Comment: срочно читать Кнута!  не имеет значение, этот счетчик увеличивается равномерно или нет. Даже если он будет туда-сюда болтаться.

Comment: @KoVadim И что же мне у Кнута надо про этот счетчик прочитать? :-) Или мне нужно про Кнутовский ГПСЧ почитать?

Answer (score 2):

Никогда, **никогда**, **НИКОГДА** не используйте `srand()` перед каждым `rand()`.

Ибо `rand()` сам каждый раз *по сути* вызывает `srand()`, инициализируя генератор очередным псевдослучайным значением, а вы мешаете его работе!

Вызвать `srand()` достаточно **один** раз, и то только для того, чтоб разные запуски программ работали с разными последовательностями значений.

P.S. Вы же, когда куда-то идете, не начинаете командовать каждой мышце - ты сократись, ты расслабься? А тут от генератора требуете примерно того же - я умней, ты генерирую то, что я говорю. Ну так если умнее - генерируйте сами, не используйте `rand()`...

Comment: Я смотрел здесь: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/
Или я чего-то не понимаю?)

Comment: @Любитель а где по вашей ссылке написано что srand нужно вызывать каждый раз?

Comment: А он там вызывается ОДИН раз, правда? В начале `main()`...

Comment: Ну-ка, заминусовавший, расскажите, как правильно `srand()` использовать! :)

Comment: Кстати, справедливости ради: rand() будет по сути вызывать srand только в случае, если размер состояния генератора меньше либо равен размеру сида. Для Mersenne Twister, к примеру, можно получить через srand() + n * rand() такое состояние, которое никаким сидом не получить ;-)

Comment: Минусую не я))) Но, я думал, это будет работать примерно так:
0 - n записывает число, которое будет сгенерированно функцией. Затем, ar с i элементом будет записано значение из n. Далее выводится ar элемент i на экран.
1 - n записывает число, которое будет сгенерированно функцией. Затем, ar с i элементом будет записано значение из n. Далее выводится ar элемент i на экран.
2 - n записывает число, которое будет сгенерированно функцией. Затем, ar с i элементом будет записано значение из n. Далее выводится ar элемент i на экран.
и так далее 20 раз.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вы обратили внимание, что я написал **по сути**, да еще и выделил курсивом? Чтобы было понятно, что это не значит, что именно в прямом смысле вызывается `srand()`... Важно, что `rand()` использует и обновляет некоторое свое состояние, а `srand()` его перешибает...

Comment: @Harry я обратил внимание, да. Для некоторых случаев там не только сути, но и фактически выполняется тот же код, что и в srand. А некоторых ни по сути, ни фактически srand не выполняется. О чем я и написал.

Comment: Ведь фактически, код работает. Но только в том случае, если массив выполняется дольше, чем 1 секунда. Каждую секунду выполнения, я буду видеть разные числа.

Comment: Попробую привести модель, пусть неверную фактически, но по сути... Примерно так - есть длинный ряд чисел, который четко определен. `rand()` при каждом вызове выдает очередное число из этого ряда. `srand()` говорит - начни с такого-то числа. Так что, вызывая `srand()` больше одного раза, вы просто заставляете каждый раз начинать выводит этот ряд с одного и того же числа. Даже если вы будете давать, скажем, последовательные значения при каждом новом вызове `srand()`, лучше не будет, так как ваше самодеятельность запросто может привести к генерации уже не совсем (или совсем не) случайных чисел.

Comment: Понимаете, случайность - это не только **разные** числа. Тогда просто берите числа подряд - не `n = random_11()`, а `n++` - вы тоже будете видеть **разные числа**. Но не случайные. Случайность проверяется очень серьезными статистическими тестами, и то, что **кажется** случайным, может вполне таковым не быть. Оно и так получается **псевдо**случайное, не надо портить еще и дополнительно...