# Создание генератора лабиринта

Tags: c

Помогите пожалуйста. Пишу генератор лабиринтов. Пользователь вводит ширину и высоту лабиринта, на основе этих данных генерируется лабиринт с одним входом и выходом(может не иметь выхода)

1. В строчке 133 выкидывает exception, когда генератором случайной последовательности направлений первой генерируется последовательность с первым элементом 1. Непонятно почему, так как передаю в функцию четвертым параметром raw 0, но `(raw - 2 <= 0) || (col == 0) || (col == width - 1)` не выполняется. Помогите разобраться
2. В функции shuffle() использую функцию `srand(time(NULL))`. Проблема в том, что эта функция будет очевидно вызываться чаще чем раз в секунду, поэтому генератором случайной последовательности будет возвращаться одна и та же последовательность. Это приводит к тому, что алгоритм получается слишком банальный, не особо сложный. Мы можем передать в srand() время в наносекундах? Как по мне это может решить проблему, но не знаю, какую функцию для этого использовать.

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

void printWarningAndExit();
void printMaze(unsigned int**, unsigned int, unsigned int);
void swap(int*, int*);
void shuffle(int*, int);
int* generateRandomDirections();
void recursion(unsigned int **, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, 
unsigned int);
unsigned int amountOfDirections = 4;
unsigned int i, j;

int main(void) {
unsigned int askCaseWrongInput = 1;
unsigned int randomEntrance;
unsigned int **maze;
unsigned int width, height;
do {
    puts("Enter the width of the maze(positive integer greater than 5)");
    scanf_s("%u", &width);
    puts("Enter the height of the maze(positive integer greater than 5)");
    scanf_s("%u", &height);
    if (width > 5 && height > 5)
    {
        break;
    }
    else {
        puts("\nEnter the correct dimension of the maze, please\n");
    }
} while (askCaseWrongInput);

if ((maze = (unsigned int**)calloc(height, sizeof(unsigned int*))) == 0) {
    printWarningAndExit();
}

for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    if ((maze[i] = (unsigned int*)calloc(width, sizeof(unsigned int))) == 0) {
        printWarningAndExit();
    }
}

//initialization the cells of maze with 1

for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        maze[i][j] = 1;
    }
}

//system time in seconds
srand(time(NULL));
//create a random coord of entrance by y
//donot include start and end coord
randomEntrance = 1 + rand() % (width - 2);
//initialize the entrance by 0

maze[0][randomEntrance] = 0;
//printMaze(maze, width, height);
recursion(maze, width, height, 0, randomEntrance);
printMaze(maze, width, height);
_getch();
return 0;
}

void printWarningAndExit() {
    puts("Memory allocation failure");
    exit(1);
}

void printMaze(unsigned int **maze, unsigned int width, unsigned int height) 
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j] == 0)
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 12);
            else {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 26);
            }
            printf("%2d ", maze[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
int temp;
temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}

void shuffle(int *array, int size) {
//todo
srand(time(NULL));

int i, j;
for (i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    j = rand() % (i + 1);
    swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
}

}

int* generateRandomDirections() {
int *randoms;
if ((randoms = (int*)calloc(amountOfDirections, sizeof(int))) == 0) {
    printWarningAndExit();
}
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < amountOfDirections; i++)
    randoms[i] = i + 1;
shuffle(randoms, amountOfDirections);
return randoms;
}

void recursion(unsigned int **maze, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, 
unsigned int raw, unsigned int col) {
    int* randDirections = generateRandomDirections();
    //for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    //printf("%d\n", randDirections[i]);
//}
//examine each direction
for (i = 0; i < amountOfDirections; i++) {
    switch (randDirections[i]) {
        //TODO!!!

    case 1: //UP
            //Whether 2 cells up is out or not

        if ((raw - 2 <= 0) || (col == 0) || (col == width - 1)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (maze[raw - 2][col] == 1) {
            maze[raw - 2][col] = 0;
            maze[raw - 1][col] = 0;
            recursion(maze, width, height, raw - 2, col);
        }
        break;
    case 2: //Right
            //Wheater 2 cells to the right is out or not
        if ((col + 2) > width - 1 || raw == 0 || raw == height - 1) {
            continue;
        }
        if (maze[raw][col + 2] == 1) {
            maze[raw][col + 2] = 0;
            maze[raw][col + 1] = 0;
            recursion(maze, width, height, raw, col + 2);
        }
        break;
    case 3: //Down
            //Wheather 2 cells down is out or not
        if ((raw + 2) > height - 1 || col == 0 || col == width - 1)
            continue;
        if (maze[raw + 2][col] == 1) {
            maze[raw + 2][col] = 0;
            maze[raw + 1][col] = 0;
            recursion(maze, width, height, raw + 2, col);
        }
        break;
    case 4: //Left
            //Whether 2 cells to the left is out or not
        if ((col - 2) < 0 || raw == 0 || raw == height - 1)
            continue;
        if (maze[raw][col - 2] == 1) {
            maze[raw][col - 2] = 0;
            maze[raw][col - 1] = 0;
            recursion(maze, width, height, raw, col - 2);
        }
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: 2. А зачем Вы хотите вызывать `srand()` много раз? Ее надо вызывать ровно один раз за время работы программы.

Comment: Потому что в функции recursion() я вызываю функцию generateRandomDirections(), которая возвращает массив случайных направлений. В ней вызывается функция shuffle(), которая перемешивает массив. Чтобы он перемешивался каждый раз по-другому, я в функции shuffle() использую srand(). Соответственно, если generateRandomDirections() будет вызываться очень много раз в recursion(), то вызываться много раз будет и shuffle(), а поэтому и srand().

Comment: Но srand() будет обновлять seed каждую секунду, что плохо, так как функция будет shuffle будет вызываться N раз в секунду, поэтому часто будут возвращаться одинаковые массивы направлений, что как по мне очень упрощает лабиринт.

Comment: Функцию `srand` обычно вызывают один единственный раз. Похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744490/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-c)